# Converting []*string to []string in golang

Tags: go

i'm new to go.
i have a function that accepts `[]string` as input, but i the input i have to pass is an `[]*string`, how do i convert `[]*string` to `[]string`.
is there any way to convert it using any utilities, or do i have to iterate it using a for-loop and construct an array?

Playground link https://play.golang.org/p/_s2g7-IfGAy

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    //Declaring an array of []*string and assigning value to it
    var a [1]*string
    var strPointer = new(string)
    *strPointer = "1"
    a[0] = strPointer
    fmt.Println(*a[0])
    // accept(a) this wont work

    //Converting to array []string
    var b []string
    for i := range a {
        b = append(b, *a[i])
    }
    accept(b)// this works

    fmt.Println(b)

}

func accept(param []string) {
    fmt.Println("Works!")
}
```

Comment: Why are you manipulating pointers to strings in the first place?

Comment: Yes, you use a for loop. If you need to do this in multiple places, put that loop in a function.

Comment: this is just an example, i get that field auto generated, so its a []*string , and i have to pass it to a function that is also autogenerated that accepts []string

Answer (score 6):

Your `accept(param []string)` expect a slice of string.

`var a [1]*string` This declares Go array with a length of `1`. So it's not a slice.

You can declare an empty slice of string pointers using this. `var a []*string`

And you have to iterate through the array and make a slice with the value of pointer elements and call the `accept` with that slice.

Example function to convert []*string to []string

```
func stringer(str []*string) []string{
    var strs []string
    for _, s := range str {
        if s == nil {
            strs = append(strs, "")
            continue
        }
        strs = append(strs, *s)
    }

    return strs
}
```

[run here](https://play.golang.org/p/IBcMSQblSJ1)

Comment: To reduce reallocation, a [minor optimization](https://play.golang.org/p/_avDpAvUsLn) is possible.

Answer (score 2):

> how do i convert []*string to []string

You cannot. This kind of type conversion not possible in Go.

> is there any way to convert it using any utilities [...]

Asking for 3rd party libraries/tools/packages is OT on SO.

> [...] or do i have to iterate it using a for-loop and construct an array

This is the only clean, normal, "idiomatic" way of doing this.